# Stop onfocus event from firing in javascript

Tags: javascript

The onFocus event keeps firing on page load and doesn't seem to work when the element goes into focus. I only want the alert to fire off when the the input comes into focus not on page load

```
//Input
var input = document.getElementById('phonenumber');
//onfocus execute function
input.onFocus = alert('test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function `alert` and assigning its return value (`undefined`) to the focus handler. Try this instead:

```
input.onfocus = function() { alert('test'); };
```

Or, perhaps more understandably:

```
function inputFocused() {
    alert('test');
}
input.onfocus = inputFocused;
```

Note that there are no parentheses after `inputFocused` in the assignment. We want to set `onfocus` to *the function itself*, not to the *result of calling* the function.